# apply copy rotation constraint to bones

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image]

Is there a way to have the pivot point of the bone chain highlighted red to be set to the bone circled in red, but have the chain inherit rotation from the bone highlighted blue? I've tried to do this with a rotation constraint on a rigify rig. It seems you cant set rotation constaints to bones within the hierarchy, so I parented a cube to the blue bone and then set the constraint to that box, but it seems to just freeze the entire rig, i cant move a single bone until the constraint is deleted.

Comment: maybe it is much easier for us to understand if you tell us your "end goal" e.g. i want my left shoulder rotate in the same way as my right shoulder does. Often we concentrate on one specific problem although the solution could be something totally easy (but other than we thought)

Comment: Is there only one armature and the bones of the red chain are part of the same armature as the blue bone? Wouldn't it be sufficient to make the red chain to be a child of the blue bone with offset?

Comment: all the bones are on the same armature. Parenting the red chain to the blue bone with offset wouldn't work because I want the red chain to keep its position relative to the red circled bone and just rotate with the leg (blue bone). I figured it out, it turns out i was trying to use an object constraint instead of a bone constraint, which is why it didn't work. I wasn't aware bones had their own constraints.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out i was trying to use object constraint instead of bone constraint. Bone constraints are found in the bone constraint properties tab when in pose mode.